# Android:menu.add() how to display string value in the center

Tags: android, string, menu

hello i have created a menu with `onCreateOptionsMenu` . Here is the code :

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    boolean result = super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return result;

}
```

It works fine but the string `menu_insert` is displayed in the far left side of the pop up menu. Is there a way to align the string to the center? sorry if it is a newbie question.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Create menu in xml layout file under res/menu/mymenu.xml and define all attributes for UI setting there.

Comment: @ManishDubey I tried that but i seems android:gravity="center" does not work

Answer (score 0):

You should use the xml to create a menu and on top of that you can use the ActionBar, [read here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)